# How can I use my own Mapbox style with Mapkit on Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mapbox

I'm wondering if this is possible? I have a lot of qualms with the Mapbox documentation; I think there are a lot of holes in it, but I am a fan of how I am able to customise my own maps with their nifty style editors. With that said, I'm trying to use a bit of the Mapkit functionality with the Mapbox design.

I'm aware that I can generally edit the colours of Mapkit maps, but I for my purposes, I need to make certain roads certain colours.

Basically, I'd like to use the Mapbox style on an MKMapView in xcode. Can I do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. Mapbox styles are for Mapbox map views. Apple don't allow third parties to customise the look of their own map-tiles in the way you mean. I've always found the Mapbox documentation pretty good. What parts do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I don’t think Mapbox’s Geocoding documentation is very helpful, I even wrote in to Mapbox for help, but they weren’t of assistance. I’ve chosen to use the ArcGIS SDK for iOS, since their Geocoding is a lot easier to implement.